# How to collect commands in a || statement?

Tags: bash

I understand that `command1 || command2` executes command 2 only if command1 fails.

What if I want to execute command2 and command3 if command1 fails, but I want to do it on one line with the use of brackets, i.e. I want to still use a '`||`' expression and avoid `if    else`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If maintained on the same line, last command in group needs a colon `;` and a space  before the closing curly brace `}`.

Example:

```sh
command1 || { command2; command3; }
```

Alternatively it can be laid-out as multiple lines like this:

```sh
command1 || {
  command2
  command3
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use curly braces to group them: `command1 || { command2; command3; }`